# Displaystyle fractions in a system of equations

Tags: equations, environments, displaystyle

I'm trying to define an environment to use with equations' systems. So far, the best solution was

```
\newenironment{eqsys}{\begin{equation}\begin{cases}}{\end{cases}\end{equation}}
```

but I noticed that if the equations had, say, partial derivative, which are fractions, those are squeezed. So I modified it, adding `\displaystyle` so the environment looked like this

```
\newenironment{eqsys}{\begin{equation}\begin{cases}\displaystyle}{\end{cases}\end{equation}}
```

but with this trick, only the *first* equation in the system is correctly typeset.

The code to get the results I get is

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newenvironment{eqsys}{\begin{equation}\begin{cases}\displaystyle}{\end{cases}\end{equation}}

\begin{document}
\begin{eqsys}
    \tan(\theta) = \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}\\
    \text{cotan}(\theta) = \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin{\theta}}
\end{eqsys}
\end{document}
```

How can I make `\displaystyle` repeat for each equation in the set?

Comment: Please compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Sorry, just forgot it. The MWE I provided will recreate the odd condition I get.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use `dcases` from the `mathtools` package

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newenvironment{eqsys}{\begin{equation}\begin{dcases}}{\end{dcases}\end{equation}}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqsys}
 \frac{1}{2}    \\
 \frac{2}{5}
\end{eqsys}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively there is `\dfrac` from the `amsmath` package, which can be used instead of `\displaystyle\frac25`, but it sounds like this would be too manual for what you want.

---

Here is how the `dcases` performs with @PeterGrill's test case

[image: screenshot]

```
\begin{eqsys}
    e = 2 \frac{1}{2}\\
    e = 2 \frac{1}{2}
\end{eqsys}
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for, I didn't know about `dcases`!

Answer (score 4):

A solution to make `\displaystyle` repeat for each equation would be to use `\everymath={\displaystyle}`, which is applied at the start of any math material. I renamed your original version as `eqsysOLD` and used it following the new version of `eqsys` for two purposes:

1. compare the output
2. test that the setting of `\everymath` is local and does not effect subsequent math material

[image]

### Known Issues:

- Even though this solution illustrates how to apply a specific command to each equation, `dcases` provides better vertical spacing. So in this specific case the solution of @cmhughes is a better alternative.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{eqsysOLD}{\begin{equation}\begin{cases}\displaystyle}{\end{cases}\end{equation}}

\newenvironment{eqsys}{\begin{equation}\everymath={\displaystyle}\begin{cases}}{\end{cases}\end{equation}}

\begin{document}
\begin{eqsys}
    e = 2 \frac{1}{2}\\
    e = 2 \frac{1}{2}
\end{eqsys}

\begin{eqsysOLD}
    e = 2 \frac{1}{2}\\
    e = 2 \frac{1}{2}
\end{eqsysOLD}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Compare the results on your test code to that when using `dcases`- you'll see that `dcases` performs significantly better

Comment: @cmhughes: Excellent point. Have included that info.

Comment: Thanks; would you mind if I include your test case in my answer?

Comment: @cmhughes: No of course not.